# Hiding the mouse cursor on a button click

Tags: java, android, cursor, mouse

I would like to know if is it possible to hide a mouse cursor in my Android app.
I've build an app an when you push the button a video starts.
For to this I disassembled a mouse to use the left click, but when I push the button the mouse cursor appears.

Can I hide it?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954520/android-hide-mouse-pointer-programmatically-in-my-own-app?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Please offer a minimal working example.