# How to set mouse cursor position in Android

Tags: android

I have a problem. In Android, when the mouse is connected, the cursor appears.

I have been thinking for a long time how to set its position in the center of the screen in order to control the camera view in 3D. I need to set its position to the center of the screen, count the offset and repeat this operation again. I will be glad to hear how to do this, as this issue has been bothering me for four months.

Unfortunately, I didn't find anything on the Internet about manipulating the Android cursor. I want to make a test Android application in Android Studio that could set and read the position of the mouse cursor on Android.

Comment: [Moving mouse pointer on Android screen programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695258/moving-mouse-pointer-on-android-screen-programmatically)

Comment: [Change Mouse Cursor/Pointer on Android](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/5725)

Comment: [PointerIcon](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/PointerIcon)